# Is there a way to update the headers in one feature file and use the Auth token from Karate.config.js?

Tags: karate

I would like to update my common headers (Accept and Content-Type) just in one feature file. however, I would like to use Authorization token which already configured in Karate.config.cs file.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers

```
* configure headers = read('classpath:my-headers.js')
```

And you can refer to variables declared in `karate-config.js` anywhere in Karate. Again read the docs, and there are multiple examples. Next time please ask a more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example